# Is it possible to set up an Apple Savings account without upgrading my iPhone to iOS 16?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-card

The situation:  I've got an Apple Card set up, and I'd like to also open an Apple Savings account (to get 4.15% interest on my spare cash), but the button to do that doesn't appear unless you've updated your phone to iOS 16, which is a problem because apparently Apple doesn't support iOS 16 on my iPhone 6s+ (it is updated to iOS 15.7.5, which it assures me is "up to date").

My question is:  is there any way for me to set up an Apple Savings account without having to buy a new iPhone?  Perhaps there is a web-based method available somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to buy a new phone, but you will have to borrow one to set this up (and potentially make any transactions once it's set up). There is almost no way I would recommend trying to fake out the registration process as you would likely get snagged for anti fraud steps they have in place to protect identity.

I love you are rocking an older phone and don't want to upgrade when it so far has worked for everything you need. Reusing a device is better than recycling and not replacing is even better for everyone. Also, who knows if Apple is rolling it out slowly and once the bank and systems are working with the "newest" they don't push an update or a button to roll it out more widely?